# Google login/search fails unless cookie is cleared

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Sometimes Google Chrome fails to log me into Gmail or even go to Google's main search page.  This doesn't happen with Firefox.  It took me a while to figure out the fix, but clearing the cookies from Chrome's Settings page works.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix the issue without clearing the cookies every time? Clearing the cookies is inconvenient because it wreaks havoc with other things (such as automatic login.)

Comment: Clearing the cookies auto-logins you in? Or after you clear cookies you have to login and from then on it works for awhile?

Comment: This sounds like your security settings are to high within Chrome.

Comment: Clearing the cookies doesn't not auto-login me. I still have to login after clearing cookies. But at least I can get in to Gmail and Google search after clearing cookies. Without clearing them, Chrome says it can't find the pages!

Comment: @ Ramhound, can you elaborate? how do you lower the security setting?